# Aggregate using array of pipelines MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a array like this

```
pipeline = [
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "cohort_name": "$CohortMonthYear",
        "segment_name": "$SegmentName",
        "driver_name": "Operating Expense"
      },
      "cohort_list": {
        "$push": {
          "driver_value": "$Operating Expense",
          "mob_value": "$MonthsOnBooks"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "cohort_name": "$CohortMonthYear",
        "segment_name": "$SegmentName",
        "driver_name": "Other fee per active"
      },
      "cohort_list": {
        "$push": {
          "driver_value": "$Other fee per active",
          "mob_value": "$MonthsOnBooks"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to aggregate the Collection by each pipeline inside the array. How to do this without needing to iterate the array and then aggregating individual pipeline?

Collection Schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cea0de29beab9b1128142e"),
    "SegmentName" : "Transactor-High-Super Prime",
    "Segment_Behaviour" : "Transactor",
    "Segment_Usage" : "High",
    "Segment_Risk" : "Super Prime",
    "CohortMonthYear" : "01-01-2010",
    "CohortQuarterYear" : "Q1 2010",
    "MonthsOnBooks" : 1,
    "Accounts" : 5400,
    "Active rate" : 0.6102349013766621,
    "Purchase per active" : 489.9747013271109495,
    "BT per active" : 270.3482080015934343,
    "CA per active" : 1.0073548882354659,
    "AMF per active" : 0.0046451682730326,
    "Late and Overlimit fee per active" : 0.0032395984480145,
    "Other fee per active" : 7.9199489691490577,
    "Purchase APR" : 0,
    "BT APR" : 0.0300000000000000,
    "Cash APR" : 0.1763020000000000,
    "Interchange Rate" : 0.0142100000000000,
    "Payment Rate" : 0,
    "BT Fee Rate" : 0.0291840000000000,
    "Cash advance fee rate" : 0.0328347765703207,
    "Unit loss rate" : 0.0000000000000000,
    "Balance Control Ratio" : 2.2999868799572565,
    "Cost of Funds" : 0.0281148836230321,
    "Marketing Cost" : 125.6961196036371575,
    "Operating Expense" : 0.8725128657629959,
    "Yield" : 0.0000000000000000,
    "ADB" : 12.3296052310066617,
    "portfolio_id" : ObjectId("56ce9f92c95a8a459ba0c580")
}
```

My current approach is outlined below. The problem with this approach is it's extremely slow.

```
for template in pipeline:
    PortfolioData.objects(portfolio_id=self.portfolio_id).aggregate(template,
                                                                             allowDiskUse=True)
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
PortfolioData.objects(portfolio_id=self.portfolio_id).aggregate(pipeline,
                                                                              allowDiskUse=True)
```

Comment: What are you using here? Looks mongengine(ish)! but would help if you actually tagged as such. Also what is your goal here, since you are basically grouping on the same things but just pushing different values into an array. Seems to me you just add both fields in the array, or is there some reason why you expect/need these as separate documents? Could do with a little more explanation.